# Can RestKit detach CoreData relationship object?

Tags: ios, json, restkit-0.20

I have a many-to-many relationship between Group and Document entities. When retrieving group, this is how JSON looks like:

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "Group 1",
  "documents": [1,2,3,4,5]
}
```

and the mapping works just fine and creates relationship between Document and Group objects.

Now let's assume group doesn't have documents anymore, so the response JSON is now

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "Group 1"
}
```

Is there a way that RestKit can automatically detach objects which no longer belong to this group (in case when no documents list is returned)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting `assignsNilForMissingRelationships=YES` ro `RKEntityMapping` object did the trick!